# Writing to SD Card always failing

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am trying to move files from any location (including internal device storage) 
to SD Card,

For that I Have

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest, and checked that it did work by checking if premissions are granted using :

`Contex.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")` and `Contex.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")`

and I have tried 3 diffrent ways to do that :

1. Files.move(original, newPath1), which comes with Guava com.google.common.io
2. this method :

   ```
   public static void move(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
       FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
       FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
       FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
       FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
       inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
       inStream.close();
       outStream.close();
   }
   ```
3. `original.renameTo(newPath1);`

I read alot of SO posts about this, and all solutions i tried did not work, I made sure the SD Card is mounted, and that i didnt have my device connected to PC while trying. I even tried 2 diffrent devices with SD Cards. Notice that i could access the image with BitmapFactory.decode() with the exact same path and i could load that image to imageview.

I am always getting EACCES (Permission denied). I dont know what else to do to solve this :(

```
11-13 11:11:54.358 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/thai2/IMG-20150702-WA0001.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:465)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSink.openStream(Files.java:245)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSink.openStream(Files.java:233)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at com.google.common.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:248)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at com.google.common.io.Files.copy(Files.java:458)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at com.google.common.io.Files.move(Files.java:673)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at xaday.ofek.ron.xaday.XaDayIntentService.handleActionMove(XaDayIntentService.java:128)
11-13 11:11:54.369 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at xaday.ofek.ron.xaday.XaDayIntentService.onHandleIntent(XaDayIntentService.java:84)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:451)
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:   ... 12 more
11-13 11:11:54.370 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/thai2/IMG-20150702-WA0001.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:465)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at xaday.ofek.ron.xaday.FileUtils.move(FileUtils.java:36)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at xaday.ofek.ron.xaday.XaDayIntentService.handleActionMove(XaDayIntentService.java:136)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at xaday.ofek.ron.xaday.XaDayIntentService.onHandleIntent(XaDayIntentService.java:84)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:451)
11-13 11:11:54.371 19192-19372/xaday.ofek.ron.xaday W/System.err:   ... 9 more
```

Just to make sure I was not locking the file in some way, I used another file manager app to execute the same file move - and it worked! why is it not working for me?!

anyone has an idea?

Comment: Is the SDCard mounted? You can check with if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))

Comment: Yes i made sure it is mounted...

Comment: one of them is 5.1 and the other is 4.4.2

Comment: Can you access the image with adb shell? Are the phones rooted? I'm afraid I fail to understand why you get this error...

Comment: I didnt try, but i can access the image with BitmapFactory.decode() with the exact same path, non of the phones are rooted

Comment: Did you put the `<uses-permission>` in the right place in Manifest? Could you check if the permission is granted by using `Contex.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission)` ?

Comment: yes, just checked that, got the premissions and still doesnt work

Comment: Are you trying to write in a root folder?

Comment: no, /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/thai2/ is definitly not a root folder, also note that another app COULD execute the same file transfer i was trying to do...

Comment: What is the other app that can execute the same file transfer?

Comment: Could you show how you get the source and destination path ?

Comment: Can you try disabling file transfer from device to computer. If u enable file transfer, The SD card is not accessible whilst you are debugging your application.

Also try DISABLING Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

Comment: @MattiaMaestrini the file explorers that i have on the devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android Kitkat (4.4), Google has changed how the developers can access to the removable storage (SD card). Quoting from [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/traditional.html):

> The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to
>   the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to
>   write to secondary external storage devices, except in their
>   package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.
>   Restricting writes in this way ensures the system can clean up files
>   when applications are uninstalled.

For this reason, even with the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, you can't write on the SD card on KitKat and higher versions.

On Android Lollipop (5.0), Google adds a new set of API that allows the developers to manage the file on the SD Card through the [Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

This StackOverflow answer explains in detail how to use the new APIs and the existing limitations:

[How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26744842/2837959)

Answer (score 0):

Is the "uses-permission" tag outside of the "application" tag in the manifest.xml?