# unable to save Mat image with cv::imwrite in a JNI native code openCv

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a problem in my native code because in my c ++ code I can not save the images I receive from the JAVA part.

I tried using `cv::imwrite` but the image is never saved in the path and in the corresponding folder.

My JNI code is as follows:

```
extern "C"{
    JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_testNativeCode_DisplayImage_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jclass obj, jintArray bufImg, jint w, jint h){

    jint *cbuf;
    cbuf = env->GetIntArrayElements(bufImg, 0);

    if(cbuf==NULL){
       return 0;
    }

    cv::Mat mImg(h,w,CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)cbuf);

    cv::imwrite("../SaveImage/img.png", mImg);
    }
}
```

I use android studio 2.3.3 and OpenCv 3.1.0. 
I put in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I want to know if it was possible to record an image with `cv::imwrite`?
How else can I do to save it?

Comment: Give absolute path to `imwrite` and see if it works.

Comment: @Zindarod I tried to set the absolute path but the problem is the same. Furthermore in Logcat there is no error...

Comment: Check the return value of `imwrite`. What is it?

Comment: imwrite return false ...so it's normal for the image not to be saved. But I do not understand why she does not have it.

Comment: Are you writing to SD card while connected to PC?

Comment: yes in my Java activity I save my bitmap image on my SD card and it works.

Comment: Check this answer for mount types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291504/android-opencv-imwrite-always-returns-false-and-fails-to-write#17044206. Also, are you sure your `Mat` object is created correctly?

Comment: ok thanks, I will look at the link. Normally the matrix is ​​created correctly. See the code above.

Comment: That might be the reason [opencv issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11488)

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem，but i solve it by this steps:

1.request permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2.Manually open the permission switch

3.Close app and clear task

4.Open your project app and try again,it it working to me.

If it is not working for you,uninstall and reinstall app,and repeat the above steps